# django-tastypie popup oauth like twitter

Tags: django, oauth, tastypie

I can't find django-tastypie example, how to make sign-in popup like twitter oauth.

Mayby django-tastypie have example or tutorial how i can make it?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for a modal window/popup that you can integrate with Django, Bootstrap has a nice one: http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#modals .